# How can I turn off the power supply to a USB port in Ubuntu 20.04? (Either from CLI or a SDK)

Tags: linux, controller, kernel, usb, power-management

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04. I need to turn off the power provided to a USB peripheral and then turn it ON again. I need to do his either from the CLI or with some SDK. Can anybody help me?

I've already seen a solution that uses a file called pm_qos_no_power_off, unfortunately I don't have this file in my folder. Why I can't find it?

I also found a solution that uses bCOnfiguration file, but I need to turn of the power, not only the peripheral.